# How to I get variables from location in nginx? 

Tags: debian, nginx

The location from nginx conf:

```
location ~/photos/resize/(\d+)/(\d+) {
    # Here var1=(\d+), var2=(\d+)
}
```

How to I get variables from location in nginx?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The regex works pretty much like in every other place that has it.

```
location ~/photos/resize/(\d+)/(\d+) {
  # use $1 for the first \d+ and $2 for the second, and so on.
}
```

Looking at examples on the nginx wiki may also help, http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration

Answer (score 17):

In addition to the previous answers, you can also set the names of the regex captured groups so they would easier to be referred later;

```
location ~/photos/resize/(?<width>(\d+))/(?<height>(\d+)) {
  # so here you can use the $width and the $height variables
}
```

see [NGINX: check whether $remote_user equals to the first part of the location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606337/nginx-check-whether-remote-user-equals-to-the-first-part-of-the-location) for an example of usage.

Comment: This is apparently necessary, if there's also another *nested* location with another regex and regex capture groups. Because inside that other location, `$1 $2 $3` etc will refer to values from the nested regex, overwriting the `$1 $2 ...` in the outer regex. An `alias /$1` in the *outer* regex, will use the `$1` from the *inner* regex, which likely results in file-not-found.

Comment: I think you can just write `(?<width>\d+)` instead of `(?<width>(\d+))`, or is there some other reason for this -- perhaps to also get `$1` as well as `$width` ?

Answer (score 4):

You may try this:

```
location ~ ^/photos/resize/.+ {
    rewrite ^/photos/resize/(\d+)/(\d+) /my_resize_script.php?w=$1&h=$2 last;
}
```